# WPF DataGrid Help please

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to make an itemssource along with a description of each column, how do I implement this? Here is the code, hope you understand what I wanted to say.

```
<DataGrid BorderThickness="0"
              Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Musics, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              FontFamily="Arial Black" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
              dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
              dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}">
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MusicName" IsReadOnly="true" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="KeyBinding" IsReadOnly="false" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Volume" IsReadOnly="false" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Slider Margin="5" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid>
```

I want to do slider with itemssource, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show the data class. Thus I'll imagine that it may look like this.

```csharp
public class MusicItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private string _keyBinding;
    private int _volume;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string KeyBinding
    {
        get => _keyBinding;
        set
        {
            _keyBinding = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public int Volume
    {
        get => _volume;
        set
        {
            _volume = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Then you need a collection of items in your ViewModel class (implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` too)

```csharp
private ObservableCollection<MusicItem> _musics;
public ObservableCollection<MusicItem> Musics
{
    get => _musics;
    set
    {
        _musics = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And finally add bindings to xaml

```xaml
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="MusicName" IsReadOnly="true" Width="*"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KeyBinding}" Header="KeyBinding" IsReadOnly="false" Width="*"/>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Volume" IsReadOnly="false" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Slider Margin="5" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Volume}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Yes but my DataGrid not updating, i dont know why( I use Catel.MVVM + Fody

Comment: @AlexPlgalyov Maybe you using `List`. Try `ObservableCollection` instead. Simply replace the Type.

Comment: Oh this working!